# Non-standard number data types in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sqldatatypes

Besides the "usual" number data type where precision is greater then scale there are many "non-standard" number data types where scale greater then precision or where scale is negative.

For example

1. `NUMBER(2, 5)` means that there are 5 digits in the fractional part, 3 of them is obligatory zeros.
2. `NUMBER(2,-6)` Here the scale is -6, which means the value is rounded to millions and the precision is 2, so 2 significant digits can be stored.

Can somebody provide examples of using such data types in practice?

Comment: I don't know of any examples off-hand, but [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/966388) is a link to an Oracle discussion similar to your question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thx for your link.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you asking to see concrete uses of such specifications in Oracle, or are you asking for examples of use cases, where one would need to use them (instead of, say, the generic `NUMBER` data type)? As in, "why would one ever **need** to use them"? Note that the latter is not a technical question; strictly speaking it would be out of scope for SO.

Comment: @mathguy Thanks for your resonse. I asked about general use of such number data types (second option in your comment). If this question doesn't fit to SO can you give me a piece of advice where I can ask this question?